# include facebook and twitter as login option

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth

How to include login with facebook and twitter option in a website.

Comment: you are going to have to be a bit more specific if you want useful answers...what language(s) are you using to build your site?  What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at the documentation for the FB and Twitter API's?  Or the documentation for any libraries that your language can use, that interface with those API's?

Comment: Facebook and twitter use OAuth, not OpenID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go look at http://www.janrain.com/products/engage

They have a very useful tool for doing this and they will walk you through the process (considering you have at least some programming knowledge). They provide code for all the major libraries including PHP, Ruby, Java, and ASP.

Comment: but the janrain is free I guess

Comment: They have a free version that only allows you to use up to 6 providers which you get to pick. There are also some other mild limitations but I find it very useful. http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/pricing has the details for each plan.